# Group Policy not replicating - Server 2012

Tags: active-directory, replication, domain-controller

I have 2 DCs.
Both are Server 2012.

For some reason Group Policy does not replicate between them and the client keeps getting :

```
The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows attempted to read the file \\domain.int\SysVol\domain.int\Policies\{F7D25262-30F3-4F13-B2FA-58122807E062}\gpt.ini
```

DNS is working fine between the 2 servers.

I ran dcdiag and the only thing suspicious I saw was this:

```
"DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=DOMAIN,DC=int
               Latency information for 3 entries in the vector were ignored.
                  3 were retired Invocations.  0 were either: read-only replicas and are not verifiably latent, or dc's no longer replicating this nc.  0 had no latency information (Win2K DC). "
```

Here's just about all info I think I could spare:

PDC has undergone non-authoritive restore.

EVENTID 4004 on secondary DC "The DFS Replication service stopped replication on the replicated folder at local path C:\Windows\SYSVOL\domain".

EVENTID 5004 but only on the PDC: "The DFS Replication service successfully established an inbound connection with partner DEV-DC for replication group Domain System Volume".

I might as well mention that I found a 7 seconds difference between the DCs.
Could that affect anything?

Comment: Can you post any relevant errors from the Application, System, Directory Services, and DFSR event logs? There's not enough here to definitively answer your question.

Comment: Eventid 4004:
The DFS Replication service stopped replication on the replicated folder at local path C:\Windows\SYSVOL\domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DFSR AUTHORITIVE RECOVERY TO THE RESCUE!

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2218556

As it turns out I had no replication whatsoever of SYSVOL and NETLOGON.
This saved my day.

Answer (score 2):

If I had to guess based on the lack of details here, I'd guess that you've had a [dirty DFS shutdown](http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2012/07/23/understanding-dfsr-dirty-unexpected-shutdown-recovery.aspx). You can verify this by looking for EventID 2213 in your DFSR log. That event log entry will also give you the exact command that you need to run to re-enable replication on the dirty volume.

Microsoft [provides guidance](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2846759) on how/when/where to enable auto-recovery on dirty shutdowns for DFS-R members.

Comment: I HAD that issue when SYSVOL was not being shared at all and that fixed it. 
As of now my Event Viewer (of the problematic DC) is clear of errors besides "No suitable default server credential exists on this system..." But to my understanding that only applies to LDAPS.

Comment: One more thing<
on the event viewer I do get a "The DFS Replication service stopped replication on the replicated folder at local path C:\Windows\SYSVOL\domain. ". But there's no resume...
On the PDC however, it does claim to re-connect successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Is SysVol replicating properly?

May be a problem with DFS-R (or, if you upgraded the domain from an older OS, FRS).

Try checking the relevant log files on the DCs.

Comment: New domain so it's DFSR.
How can I tell the "properly" part?
I tried restarting the service and event viewer said it was going down and then successfully managed to connect for replication.
On the other hand, DFS Management Health Report shows replication as "pending"...